# Problema al ejecutar un combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Cuando se cargan los combobox mediante un servicio me trae los datos pero el diseño del segundo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

combo se distorciona.Este es el xaml que utilizo para crear los combo en ambos casos son iguales no se por el segundo lo esta mostrando de esa forma

```
<Label Content="Tipo Socio:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontWeight="Medium" Height="26" Margin="10,187,0,0" />
<ComboBox x:Name="cbTipoSocio"  Height="29" Background="White"  Width="176" Margin="10,213,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  SelectedValuePath="CodigoTipoSocio" DisplayMemberPath="NombreTipoSocio" />


<Label Content="Estado Socio:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="DarkOrange" FontWeight="Medium" Height="26" Margin="189,187,0,0" />
<ComboBox x:Name="cbEstadoSocio"  Height="29" Background="White"  Width="176" Margin="191,213,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          SelectedValuePath="CodigoEstadoSocio" DisplayMemberPath="NombreEstadoSocio" />
```

SocioView.xaml.cs

```
cbEstadoSocio.ItemsSource = soc.GetAllEstadoSocio().ToList();
cbEstadoSocio.DisplayMemberPath = "NombreEstadoSocio";
cbEstadoSocio.SelectedValuePath = "CodigoEstadoSocio";
```

Socio.svc.cs

```
    public List<EstadoSocio> GetAllEstadoSocio()
    {
        List<EstadoSocio> listEstadoSocio = new List<EstadoSocio>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SgbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT '0' as CodigoEstadoSocio, '' as NombreEstadoSocio UNION SELECT  CodigoEstadoSocio, NombreEstadoSocio FROM EstadoSocio";
            con.Open();


            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                EstadoSocio estSocio = new EstadoSocio();
                estSocio.CodigoEstadoSocio = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CodigoEstadoSocio"].ToString());
                estSocio.NombreEstadoSocio = dr["NombreEstadoSocio"].ToString();
                listEstadoSocio.Add(estSocio);
            }
            return listEstadoSocio.ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
public class EstadoSocio
{
    public int CodigoEstadoSocio { get; set; }
    public string NombreEstadoSocio { get; set; }
}
```

Basicamente todos los combox se cargan de la misma forma

Se agredece la ayuda brindada

Comment: Buenos días con el código aportado no consigo replicar el error de los espacios, iría bien que publicaras más trozo del xaml y los tipos de datos que absorbe el combobox en el itemsource. También puede ser que esté detectando un dato como un espacio en blanco, ya que coinciden con la medida de la fuente de los valores. Saludos